# manage azure resource manager storage powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-resource-manager

I'm facing following issue

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
New-AzureStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "XYZ" -Name "VmTemplateStorage" -Type "Standard_LRS"
# lists the account
Get-AzureStorageAccount

Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "ABC" -CurrentStorageAccountName -"VmTemplateStorage"

# now this outputs error saying: Storage account 'VmTemplateStorage' was not found.
Get-AzureStorageContainer
```

I'm aware that I can create storage account in "classic" mode. But then I'm unable to use it as a source for vm images deployed using resource manager.

This way however, I'm unable to manage the account and upload blobs using powershell.

Any ideas how to manage resource manager based storage accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following new PowerShell commands to manage ARM (Azure Resource Manager) based storage accounts.

Note: You need to update your Azure PowerShell later versions which support this new feature such as the November 2015 release. Also, the **Switch-AzureMode** command is deprecated in the latest release.

```
New-AzureRmStorageAccount
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount
Remove-AzureRmStorageAccount
```